# Environmental Alkylating Agents

Tags: environmental-chemistry

I am looking for the names of some environmental alkylating agents (in context of DNA damages) found for example in the fume produced by industry. Most of the papers which I have found is concentrated on cigarette smoke, chemotherapy ect. I found something about methyl chloride, that is produced by plants and fungi, but also industrially. However there is no more details about that industrial part and in general the amount of methyl chloride in the air is rather low. Are there more relevant examples? Also I came across the information that alkylating agents may be found in food, but again there was no details.

Comment: Mutagen X is found in chlorinated drinking water and can cause DNA damage by adduct formation: http://www.oehha.ca.gov/prop65/pdf/MX_HID.pdf

Answer (score 1):

A much more significant example of this is methyl bromide, which has historically been used as a soil fumigant. Its use has been slowed phased out due to its toxicity and ozone depletion abilities.

Comment: This is interesting in general. Could you please provide some further reading material, a source of any kind.

Comment: Here's a ling to an open source review paper on alternatives to methyl bromide: http://dx.doi.org/10.1094/PHYTO.2002.92.12.1337 . As for other sources, many of the good papers on the topic are in journals which require subscription or payment. It you're at a university, I recommend checking there, or at least using Google Scholar( http://scholar.google.com/ ) to search for something like "Methyl Bromide Poisoning".

Comment: It would improve your post immensely, if you would [edit] in this information.